# NPE when Chromecast Android sender connects to receiver

Tags: android, chromecast

In my android sender app, after selecting a Chromecast receiver, when the app does `apiClient.connect()`, logcat shows the following stack trace for a NullPointerException:

```
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.dg.a(Unknown Source)
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.dw.w(Unknown Source)
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.dw$f.onServiceConnected(Unknown Source)
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.dy$a$a.onServiceConnected(Unknown Source)
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1202)
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1219)
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
02-16 13:55:10.130: E/AndroidRuntime(7780):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I believe I've set up the apiClient correctly, as I've virtually copied the code for it from the HelloWorld example.

Here's the code that is calling apiClient.connect. The Receiver class is just a POJO tht passes stuff around in the app. listeners is an instance of an inner class that extends and implements all the needed listeners.

```
public void launch(Receiver receiver, Activity activity) {
    String receiverName = null;
    if (receiver != null) {
        receiverName = receiver.name;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "::launch(" + receiverName + ")");
    try {
        unlaunch();
        launchedReceiver = receiver;
        castDevice = launchedReceiver.castDevice;
        Builder optionsBuilder = Cast.CastOptions.builder(castDevice,
                                                          listeners);
        CastOptions options = optionsBuilder.build();
        GoogleApiClient.Builder apiBuilder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity);
        apiBuilder.addApi(Cast.API, options)
                  .addConnectionCallbacks(listeners)
                  .addOnConnectionFailedListener(listeners);
        apiClient = apiBuilder.build();
        apiClient.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "exception launching receiver", e);
    }
}

public void unlaunch() {
    String receiverName = null;
    if (launchedReceiver != null) {
        receiverName = launchedReceiver.name;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "::launch(" + receiverName + ")");
}
```

Googling various phrases from the stack trace hasn't so far turned up anything that's helpful.

Any body got an ideas on this? I've spent a few hours trying things but no luck so far. I'll continue to experiment, but I could use a pointer or two as to where to go with this.

Comment: Could you add more of the log, or is that all you have for the exception? Also, please post your sender so we can see what the flow is.

Comment: That's about it in the log for the exception. It happens a second or two after the app calls apiClient.connect(), and there's just the usual background noise in the log until the NPE stacktrace.

Comment: When I try to post the code that is calling apiCLient.connect(), stack overflow says it's too big. How can I post the code, it's about 25 lines?

Comment: Please show your sender, you can update your original post to have room to add the sender code

Comment: I've editted the original post to show the code that calls apiClient.connect().

Comment: please turn on debugging (set it on the builder: optionsBuilder.setDebuggingEnabled()) so we can see more info. Also include some of that "noise" log since I'd like to see a reference to your code somewhere in the log.

Comment: Ali: after further investigation, I discovered that the launch() method was being called with a receiver object whose castDevice was null. This was happening because the onRouteSelected() callback from MediaRouter was being called with a routeInfo whose extras didn't include a CastDevice. Not sure why this is happening. I put defensive code in the onRouteSelected() callback to check for this, and just return from the callback without attempting to launch(). When this happens, almost immediately another onRouteCallback() occurs with a valid CastDevice, and launching proceeds.

Comment: Jim, I am very interested to understand how that null can happen. Can you create a sample that can reproduce that reliably? We shouldn't see such thing and I want to make sure we are not running into any hidden bugs. If you need to communicate with me privately, please let me know.

Comment: Ali: If we're going to get into sharing any more of the app, we need to do that privately.

Comment: Jim: please click the 'Contact Us' link in the bottom left-hand corner of the developer console and file a support case. Please mention there that it should be sent to me (Ali Naddaf) and then our support folks will route it to me; you can attach a sample project that exhibits that issue there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue - again related to Google Play services 4.2. My app does use Chromecast, but in my case this crash happens on app start (not even trying to connect to a Chromecast device).

While I have not seen this on my test devices, the issue first occurred when a user upgraded from older version of my app (that was not using Google Play services) to the newer version that did (for Chromecast support). That happened to the same user on 2 different devices (phone and a tablet). In both cases he was able to recover by un-installing and re-installing the app. This probably has cleared something in the app settings/cache etc that made it work.

Attached is the stack trace below that was captured by my Exception handling (exception is exactly the same as the one in the original question):

```
[ java.lang.NullPointerException ] nulljava.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.dg.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.dw.w(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.dw$f.onServiceConnected(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.dy$a$a.onServiceConnected(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1097)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1114)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4962)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: There isn't enough info to see how that is happening

Comment: Based on the source code, it seems that the only way this can be happening is that if you have selected a device that is not really a cast device. Can you verify that please?

Comment: Yes, that was the case (somewhat). The issue turned out to be (at least in my case) related to constructing the media route selector. I had:

builder.addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast(AppId()));
builder.addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO);

Comment: Just to be clear - there was no attempt to connect to any cast device at that time. Seems like that "bad" MediaRouteSelector was used internally (by Play Services maybe?) in the code paths related to the UI for displaying the MediaRouteButton. Removing thebuilder.addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO) fixed the problem.